# C++ Sqrt function

Tags: c++, function, sqrt

when i compile my program it doesnt seem to execute my formula i cant figure what i am doing wrong help would be appreciated

```
int main ()
  {
int distance, Xvalue, Yvalue;
double x1,y1,x2,y2;

cout << "\n Please enter X1 value: ";
cin  >> x1;
cout << " Please enter X2 value: ";
cin  >> x2;
cout << "\n Please enter Y1 value: ";
cin  >> y1;
cout << " Please enter Y2 value: ";
cin  >> y2;
    Xvalue = (x1 - x2);
    Yvalue = (y1 - y2);
distance = sqrt(Xvalue * Xvalue + Yvalue * Yvalue);

cout << "This is the distance between the two points" <<distance<< 


   cout << endl << endl;
   system ("pause");
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What does it do when you execute it?

Comment: Your formula is wrong, for starters.

Comment: where's the rest of the code? That won't even compile

Comment: Hint - `y1 - y1` is `0`.  And you probably want a `+` on the `distance` calculation line, too.

Comment: Please post code that compiles.  If it does not compile, pay attention to the compiler's diagnostics.  If that does not help, rephrase your question in terms of "How to resolve these compiler errors?".

Answer (score 2):

Change distance, Xvalue and Yvalue to doubles

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this might be part of your problem:

```
Xvalue = (x1 - x2);
Yvalue = (y1 - y1);
```

it probably should be:

```
Xvalue = (x1 - x2);
Yvalue = (y1 - y2);
```

Comment: -_- i didnt notice that but it still doesnt sqrt my answer

Answer (score 1):

Difference of double variables can be a `double` and your `Yvalue` always computes to `zero`.

Actually, your formula itself is wrong.

```
Distance Formula: Given the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2),
```

the distance between these points is given by the formula:

```
d = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

note that u are subtracting instead of adding the squares of differences.

```
double x1,y1,x2,y2,distance, Xvalue, Yvalue;
Xvalue = (x1 - x2);
Yvalue = (y1 - y2);
distance = sqrt(Xvalue * Xvalue + Yvalue * Yvalue);
```

Comment: it doesnt compile when i try that way =\

Comment: My changes will not affect the compilation of your code. Infact I have just mentioned minor corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2)+pow((y2-y1),2));

Comment: Please markdown your code and try to add some description for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

first cout input values so you can be sure if the problem is not in the input

```
cout<<x1<<endl;
cout<<x2<<endl;
cout<<y1<<endl;
cout<<y2<<endl;
```

then you are trying to cout... cout!

```
cout<<"this is the"<< distance << cout ... // cout again, is not very good!
```

try

```
cout<< "this is the"<< distance <<endl;
cout << endl << endl;
```

and anyway.. unless you need those "int" for specific reason is better to have doubles. (you can still round down them later with "floor(value)")

Answer (score -1):

## include

## include

int main(void)

{
  float x1, x2, y1, y2, Distance;

printf("value of x2: ");
scanf("%f",&x2);

printf("value of x1: ");
scanf("%f",&x1);

printf("value of y2: ");
scanf("%f",&y2);

printf("value of y1: ");
scanf("%f",&y1);

Distance = sqrt(pow((x2-x1),2)+pow((y2-y1),2));
printf("The distance between (X2,X1) and (Y2,Y1) is %f", Distance);

return 0;

}